# Why my extension can't be searched in Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

My extension is published on 2011-11-17. I search it in the Chrome Web Store with its full name "Notify All", but never listed. Why? How does the search engine works? Thanks.

My extension is: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pfpnamijjddnpholapdkhokmgnfkdfpp

Comment: Searching for "Notify All" displays your extension fine for me (in New Zealand): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/%22Notify%20All%22

Comment: My result is always:Google Calendar, TweetDeck, Google Voice, Sliver Bird.... Mime is never listed. (I chose my location to "United States") How does that search engine work?